# How do I configure Spring Boot JTA + Bitronix?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, jta, bitronix

I read many articles, but still did not understand how to make an application on Spring Boot JTA + Bitronix myself. Usually nowhere is it explained what parameters are needed for what, and many articles were generally written 10 years ago.

Are there any detailed tutorials on this topic somewhere?